# Laravel eloquent hasmanythrough get count

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-9

I use laravel 9.x

I am trying to get the count of the Content_hashtag and combine it into the tag,

I have 4 tables like the following:

```
 Chapter
 bp_chapter_id,
 bp_chapter_name,

 Section
 bp_section_id,
 bp_chapter_id,
 bp_tag_id,

 Content_hashtag
 bp_ch_id, 
 bp_tag_id, 
 bp_content_id

 Hashtag
 bp_tag_id,
 bp_hashtag_name
```

At the model , i have using hasmanythrough like following:

```
Chapter Model : 

    public function Tag()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Tag::class, Section::class, 'bp_chapter_id','bp_tag_id','bp_chapter_id','bp_tag_id');
    }

Controller: 
   $sections= chapter::with('tag')->get();
```

And here is the result :

```
[
    {
        "bp_chapter_id": 1,
        "bp_chapter_name": "test",
        "tag": [
            {
                "bp_tag_id": 62,
                "bp_hashtag": "test",
                "laravel_through_key": 1
            },
]
```

and this is what i expected at the result:

```
[

    {
        "bp_chapter_id": 1,
        "bp_chapter_name": "test",
        "tag": [
            {
                "bp_tag_id": 62,
                "bp_hashtag": "test",
                "laravel_through_key": 1,
                **"content_hashtag_count": 0**
            },

]
```

how can i get the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the content_hashtag_count field in your result, you can use the withCount method in your Eloquent query.

First, you need to define a relation between the Content_hashtag model and the Tag model. You can do this by adding the following method to the Tag model:

```
public function contentHashtags()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Content_
    hashtag::class, 'bp_tag_id', 
    'bp_tag_id');
}
```

Then controller looks like that :

```
   $sections = 
    Chapter::with(['tag' => 
    function($query) {
     $query- 
    >withCount('contentHashtags');
   }])->get();
```

This will add a content_hashtags_count field to each Tag record in the result, with the count of Content_hashtag records that belong to that Tag.